# Graphics problem after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, intel-graphics, 13.04

I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04, and am having graphics bugs. Either the screen is blank with random colored pixels at the top of the screen or I get repeated patterns or colors.

I reinstalled (clean) 12.10, and then upgraded to 13.04 right after install. Same issues.

I *did* install intel graphics drivers from Intel's driver installation package on my original 12.10 install.

Setup : Intel Pentium G2020 (Ivy Bridge), Biostar H61 ITX motherboard

Comment: Does this look like your problem ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/286522/graphical-failure-after-upgrade-to-13-04

Comment: Yes, that looks very familiar. Have you gotten anywhere with this?

Comment: Nope, my question is getting downvotes :(

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure of what is causing this issue because this can be caused by a lot of things, however I have had something similar to this. Here is how I fixed it.

You are going to need to download [Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) from the website. Then put it on your favourite installation Medium, whether it is a USB or a DVD. Then go and install it. When the installer is first starting and you see the human icon, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Ubiquity Human Icon]

Then you will see this screen:

[image: Ubiquity chose Language]

Chose your language (I assume English), and Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Next, hit <kbd>F6</kbd>. In that menu, select `nomodeset`. Then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>

[image: nomodeset]

Now select `Install Ubuntu` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Install Ubuntu]

You will now go back to your regular installation. What you have done is set that the graphics to not run inside the kernel. I don't know the specifics, but in summary, usually fixes these issues.

Good Luck. Hope it works.